# gometalinter save output into xml

Tags: go

I started using gometalinter on my project and when I run it I want to save the output into an XML file. I run the command `gometalinter --checkstyle` but it's only printing it on the console. Is there a flag or something to save the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no flag to save the output but you can do this

```
gometalinter --checkstyle > linterReport.xml
```